One or more errors occurred. (Error: Could not find 'Blazor._internal.attachRootComponentToElement' ('attachRootComponentToElement' was undefined)
I´m working in a blazor wasm hosted app, i had problems with posting on IIS so searching solutions, I installed de nugget packet: Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browse-wasm, then it seems to be incompatible with something and I unistalled, then the app stop working and bring me this error:
VM11 blazor.webassembly.js:1 Error: One or more errors occurred. (Error: Could not find 'Blazor._internal.attachRootComponentToElement' ('attachRootComponentToElement' was undefined).)
    at Jn (marshal-to-js.ts:349:18)
    at Tl (marshal-to-js.ts:306:28)
    at 00b21cf6:0x1fad7
    at 00b21cf6:0x1bf9f
    at 00b21cf6:0xf16c
    at 00b21cf6:0x1e7f1
    at 00b21cf6:0x1efe7
    at 00b21cf6:0xcfbc
    at 00b21cf6:0x44213
    at e.<computed> (cwraps.ts:338:24)

I tried to install it again but it did´t work and I dont know what to do.
this is my .csproject Risk.Server
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\Risk.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\Risk.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>


and this is my index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Risk</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Risk.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/software-base.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" autostart="false"></script>
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.downloadFile = async (fileName, byteArray) => {
            const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(byteArray)]);
            const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
            anchorElement.href = url;
            anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
            anchorElement.click();
            anchorElement.remove();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    </script>


</body>

</html>



I forgot, it also gives this error:  wasm-feature-detect.1.5.1.js:1
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()


First remove the reference of the problematic package from the all the project. then clean the soltion and and rebuild it you have two references to blazor.webassembly.js. Remove the duplicate and keep only one:<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>.  Verify the path _framework and ensure that it contains the required files. run this command dotnet restore

It actually works, thank you.

First remove the reference of the problematic package from the all the project. then clean the solution and rebuild it you have two references to blazor.webassembly.js.
Remove the duplicate and keep only one:. Verify the path _framework and ensure that it contains the required files. run this command dotnet restore
